Unable to tag the right elements to scrape a website using Selenium in Python
I am trying to scrape this website which would display utility bills information once details have been inserted. The website requires me to insert some info as well as clicking on some options.
I have been reading about Selenium and how to implement the "fill the details" and "click the button" option. However, I found hard to understand what "code" to insert from the html of the website to make the python code work.
I am basically stuck at the very beginning:
url = 'https://www.facile.it/energia-dual-fuel/preventivo.html'

# Your information
name = 'Mario Rossi' # random name
email = 'test@live.it' # random email
phone = '3333333333' # random number
zip_code = '20019' # some random postcode for Milan

# Initialize the Chrome WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# Open the website
driver.get(url)


So far so good, from here onwards I find very hard to make it work. I tried to retrieve info by Id and NAME but it didn't really work. I also inspected the html of the websites but didn't really understand what to take it from it.
name_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Nome e Cognome')

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="Nome e Cognome"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=125.0.6422.61); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

name_field.send_keys(name)


# Also tried something like this (but it didn't work either):

name_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'Nome e Cognome')))


It would be helpful to have an example of what to do with the "click" option and with the "fill the form" option so that I understand better how to do it.
Can anyone help me with this?

Here is one way of interacting with that website:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,1080")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
driver.get('https://facile.it/energia-dual-fuel/preventivo.html')
print('visited page')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="nome"]'))).send_keys('Giorgia')
print('sent name')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="cognome"]'))).send_keys('Meloni')
print('sent surname')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="email"]'))).send_keys('italia@italia.it')
print('sent surname')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="telefono_cellulare"]'))).send_keys('0031234567890')
print('sent tel')
terms_accepted_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@value="group_privacy_main"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", terms_accepted_box);
print('accepted privacy terms')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@data-t="xl-successPrimary"]'))).click()
print('confirmed details')

You will see the actions in the browser, and in terminal:
visited page
sent name
sent surname
sent surname
sent tel
accepted privacy terms
confirmed details

You will need correct details of course, and also Comune di attivazione fornitura. Selenium documentation can be found here.

Thanks very helpful. What I am still missing is how to click on a different option on a question like: *A quali tariffe sei interessato? I have been trying things like: wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#117e70dca67~ ._11g41z21i ._13nv9p1y'))).click() or wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@name="Solo Luce"]'))).click(). No success unfortunately. Any hint here?

@Rollo99: it all depends on what error trace you are receiving. Most likely that element is being obfuscated by another overlaying element. In such case, use the Javascript click method -- see how terms are accepted in my script above.

I'm assuming that name field is a text box. So you need to first click on it, then send the input and then press enter.
  name_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Nome e Cognome')
  name_field.click()
  name_field.send_keys(name)
  name_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

If it still doesn't work, then try to use some sleep or wait function to wait for the write to fully load and then try it.

I actually get the error I mention right after running   name_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Nome e Cognome')

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
